# Prove/disprove that $ \mathbb{R}^2 / $~ is hausdorff, when: $(x_1,x_2) $~$(y_1,y_2)$ if there is $t>0$ such that $x_2 = tx_1 $ and $ty_2 = y_1$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

We look at the following equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$(x_1,x_2) $~$(y_1,y_2)$ iff there exists $t>0$ such that $x_2 = tx_1 $ and $ty_2 = y_1$

The task is to prove/disprove: $Y = \mathbb{R}^2 / $~ is Hausdorff.

Well, I am not sure how exactly to approach this problem. I tried to prove this stright forward but had no lack.

I also thought of maybe finding a homeomorphism from $Y$ to a Hausdorff space, which will prove it since homeomorphims, preserves Hausdorff. But I couldn't find such of a homeomorphism.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purposes of visualization, it may help you to think of this space as the quotient by a group action: let $(0,\infty)$ act on $\mathbb{R}^2$ according to $t\cdot(x,y) = (tx,y/t)$. The orbits of this action are mainly hyperbolas, as shown in the plot below, though there are also five other "exceptional" orbits (what are they?).

[image]

Although it isn't actually necessary, things probably look a little more standard if we work with the "logarithm" of this action, i.e. convert it into into an action of the additive group $\mathbb{R}$ so that the orbits of the action are integral curves of the vector field associated to the action. In this form, the $\mathbb{R}$ action is the linear action $t \cdot (x,y) = (e^t x , e^{-t}y)$ and, taking $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}$, the generating vector field is the linear vector field, $X(x,y) = (x,-y)$, whence the plot shown above.

I think by staring at this picture, you will probably convince yourself quite quickly that the quotient should not be Hausdorff. Any neighbourhoods (saturated with respect to the equivalence relation or not) of the two disjoint orbits consisting of the positive and negative $x$-axis must overlap. I encourage you to fill in the details yourself.

Comment: Great answer, especially with the visual aid.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: The equivalence relation in the problem is "$(x_1,x_2) $~$(y_1,y_2)$ iff there exists $t>0$ such that $x_2 = tx_1 $ and $ty_2 = y_1$" whereas this answer seems to be about the orbit equivalence relation "$(x_1,x_2) $~$(y_1,y_2)$ iff there exists $t>0$ such that $y_1 = tx_1 $ and $ty_2 = x_2$".  The relation in the problem isn't actually an equivalence relation (all points in the 1st & 3rd quadrants are related to $(0,0)$ but not all to each other), so the relation in this answer might be what was intended.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Well spotted! I thought the notation encoded a $1$st point and a $2$nd point in the "$xy$-plane", but actually it encodes a point $x$ and a point $y$ in the "$12$-plane". Anyway, as you say, it seems reasonably likely that the inverse error had already been committed, whether by the OP or the author of the problem, and that my error cancelled it out.